# Copy values from specific cells in rows to a column in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to gain understanding on writing **functions** in **Microsoft Excel**. I created a simple example to practice a few simple actions; namely, **how to get all values in a specified order from rows (between two given cells and which have a specified range) and copy them on a separate column**.

As can be seen on the example below, I have 3 sets of values (`ALPHA`, `BETA` and `GAMMA`), each with numeric values ranging on 4 columns (A, B, C and D) and on 7 rows where on the last row the last column (column D) is empty. Each set of value has a title name residing on column A before each values (i.e. on (A,1), (A,9) and (A, 18)).

```
          A           B           C           D
1     ALPHA_VALUES              
2     2.93E+02  7.15E+02    1.22E+03    1.27E+03
3     1.84E+03  1.77E+03    1.88E+03    1.97E+03
4     2.10E+03  2.14E+03    2.17E+03    2.18E+03
5     2.10E+03  2.20E+03    2.19E+03    2.18E+03
6     1.33E+03  1.25E+03    1.30E+03    1.13E+03
7     9.83E+02  9.03E+02    8.20E+02    7.32E+02
8     5.37E+02  4.24E+02    2.93E+02        
9     BETA_VALUES               
10    0.00E+00  8.71E-10    2.53E-09    1.50E-08
11    5.20E-07  2.11E-06    6.49E-06    1.61E-05
12    6.38E-05  1.08E-04    1.68E-04    2.43E-04
13    4.32E-04  5.51E-04    7.38E-04    1.00E-03
14    1.88E-03  2.54E-03    3.33E-03    4.27E-03
15    6.06E-03  6.92E-03    7.68E-03    8.31E-03
16    2.67E-03  1.44E-03    0.00E+00        
17    GAMMA_VALUES          
18    0.00E+00  5.85E-14    8.74E-12    1.47E-10
19    1.29E-08  7.45E-08    3.01E-07    9.09E-07
20    4.51E-06  8.04E-06    1.27E-05    5.81E-05
21    2.89E-05  3.46E-05    4.04E-05    4.44E-05
22    3.83E-05  2.69E-05    1.70E-05    1.27E-05
23    7.26E-06  4.85E-06    3.01E-06    1.78E-06
24    6.17E-14  2.22E-15    0.00E+00
```

I want to copy each of the 3 sets above on a separate column. For fetching the data on the cells of each row, the order I want the data to be copied to a new separate column if from left to right; i.e. for `APLHA_VALUES` the resulting column should be like so:

```
2.93E+02    
7.15E+02
1.22E+03
1.27E+03
1.84E+03
1.77E+03
1.88E+03
1.97E+03
2.10E+03
2.14E+03
2.17E+03
2.18E+03
1.33E+03
1.25E+03
1.30E+03
1.13E+03
9.83E+02
9.03E+02
8.20E+02
7.32E+02
5.37E+02
4.24E+02
2.93E+02
```

Any sample code to get me starting on how to fetch and copy the specified data on a column will be much appreciated.

**MODIFIED EXAMPLE** (*to better demonstrate a formula's workings*):

~Added a 1 extra column and 3 extra rows for each set. Also added some data on the first 6 lines which do not participate in the formula.

```
          A           B           C           D           E
1     blah           
2     blah           4124
3     blah           342
4     blah           321
5     blah           43
6     blah 
7     ALPHA_VALUES              
8     2.93E+02  7.15E+02    1.22E+03    1.27E+03    1.27E+03
9     1.84E+03  1.77E+03    1.88E+03    1.97E+03    1.97E+03
10    2.10E+03  2.14E+03    2.17E+03    2.18E+03    1.97E+03
11    2.10E+03  2.20E+03    2.19E+03    2.18E+03    1.97E+03
12    1.33E+03  1.25E+03    1.30E+03    1.13E+03    1.97E+03
13    9.83E+02  9.03E+02    8.20E+02    7.32E+02    1.97E+03
14    2.10E+03  2.20E+03    2.19E+03    2.18E+03    1.97E+03
15    1.33E+03  1.25E+03    1.30E+03    1.13E+03    1.97E+03
16    9.83E+02  9.03E+02    8.20E+02    7.32E+02    1.97E+03    
17    5.37E+02  4.24E+02    2.93E+02        
18    BETA_VALUES               
19    0.00E+00  8.71E-10    2.53E-09    1.50E-08    1.50E-08
20    5.20E-07  2.11E-06    6.49E-06    1.61E-05    1.50E-08
21    6.38E-05  1.08E-04    1.68E-04    2.43E-04    1.50E-08
22    4.32E-04  5.51E-04    7.38E-04    1.00E-03    1.50E-08
23    1.88E-03  2.54E-03    3.33E-03    4.27E-03    1.50E-08
24    6.06E-03  6.92E-03    7.68E-03    8.31E-03    1.50E-08
25    4.32E-04  5.51E-04    7.38E-04    1.00E-03    1.50E-08
26    1.88E-03  2.54E-03    3.33E-03    4.27E-03    1.50E-08
27    6.06E-03  6.92E-03    7.68E-03    8.31E-03    1.50E-08
28    2.67E-03  1.44E-03    0.00E+00        
29    GAMMA_VALUES          
30    0.00E+00  5.85E-14    8.74E-12    1.47E-10    1.47E-10
31    1.29E-08  7.45E-08    3.01E-07    9.09E-07    1.47E-10
32    4.51E-06  8.04E-06    1.27E-05    5.81E-05    1.47E-10
33    2.89E-05  3.46E-05    4.04E-05    4.44E-05    1.47E-10
34    3.83E-05  2.69E-05    1.70E-05    1.27E-05    1.47E-10
35    7.26E-06  4.85E-06    3.01E-06    1.78E-06    1.47E-10
36    2.89E-05  3.46E-05    4.04E-05    4.44E-05    1.47E-10
37    3.83E-05  2.69E-05    1.70E-05    1.27E-05    1.47E-10
38    7.26E-06  4.85E-06    3.01E-06    1.78E-06    1.47E-10
39    6.17E-14  2.22E-15    0.00E+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is INDEX:

```
=INDEX($A:$D,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+1+MATCH(F$1,$A:$A,0),MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,4)+1)
```

Put it in F2 copy over two columns and down 27.

[image]

Comment: Could you please offer a small description of your workings?

Comment: It's just math.  The row increases as it is filled/dragged down.  as that does the row and column references change.  The `INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+1` starts at 1 then every four rows it increases by 1.  The `MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,4)+1` repeats the pattern 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,... and the MATCH(F$1,$A:$A,0) finds the correct line to start.

Comment: Confused. You mean it starts at 1 then every four COLUMNS it increases by 1, correct? Also, I dont get how for BETA it starts from row 10.. Please explain I am an Excel noob

Comment: No I meant rows. As the formula is dragged down every four rows it increments by one. Put that part in a cell and drag it down to see what it does. The match portion is how it finds the correct row. It finds and returns the row where each name is found. Then it just a matter of adding the two together to get the correct row reference to return to the index formula.

Comment: Having trouble recreating it.. I copy the formula in F2. But the "copy over two columns and down 27" part troubles me. Perhaps you could make more explicit for me? Thanks!

Comment: hover over the lower left corner of F2, the cursor will change to a thin cross.  Click and drag over two columns.  Then with all three highlighted hover over the lower left of H2 till the cursor changes to the thin cross click and drag down 27 rows.  Or just highlight F2 copy it.  Highlight F2:H:28 and paste.  Or use Fill from the Home tab.

Comment: Just to understand the formula and its mechanics I added slightly modified example (extra column and extra rows for each set). Could you please provide a formula for that as well so I can compare and better understand?

Comment: Changing the question after getting an answer is considered bad form.

Comment: just change all the `4` to `5`