# Columns to multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I would like a macro to convert the following

```
NAME COLOR1 COLOR2 COLOR3 COLOR4
jane   blue   pink    red   teal
john    red  black  green   gold
```

to

```
NAME COLOR
jane blue
jane pink
jane red
jane teal
john red
john black
john green
john gold
```

I have tried using the built-in transpose tool, but that does not seem to work. It seems like I need a custom script...

Comment: What have you tried as far as macros go? There's a thousand ways to skin this cat, a starting place for helping you would be great.

Comment: This can also be done with INDEX() and some math.

Comment: How I personally would go about this would be with a for loop nested in a for loop. One to cycle through the names, and the nested one to cycle through the colors.

Comment: For a flexible VBA solution, here's an old answer of mine to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10922351/293078

Comment: Here is a formula version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419131/copy-values-from-specific-cells-in-rows-to-a-column-in-ms-excel/39419333?noredirect=1#comment66166062_39419333

Comment: You can also unpivot the data with Power Query or the old way with the wizard https://www.google.com/#q=excel+unpivot&tbm=vid

Answer (score 1):

With data in rows **2** and **3**, pick a cell and enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9999,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0))
```

Next to it enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4))
```

and copy these down:

[image]

*If you really love macros, have the macro deposit and copy the formulas.*